# openstack how to solve 0 dhcp agents active

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I am trying to get overstack to work on my machine but I can't create dhcp agents to attach to a port.

I get this debug message in the console if i create, or delete a port
`Agent healthcheck: found 0 active agents agent_health_check`
any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Do you have a dhcp agent running? (neutron-dhcp-agent)

Comment: this is my neutron-dhcp-agent log file, and it is running. `DEBUG oslo_concurrency.lockutils [-] Lock "_check_child_processes" acquired by "neutron.agent.linux.external_process._check_child_processes" :: waited 0.000s inner /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_concurrency/lockutils.py:273
2018-11-07 11:29:29.790 3293 DEBUG oslo_concurrency.lockutils [-] Lock "_check_child_processes" released by "neutron.agent.linux.external_process._check_child_processes" :: held 0.001s inner /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_concurrency/lockutils.py:285
` @eandersson